# nginx server_name with directories "domain.com/directory1/directory2"

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy and I have the following site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.com/directory1/directory2;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://google.com;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

 }
```

when I run nginx -t, I'm getting the following information:

```
nginx: [warn] server name "domain.com/directory1/directory2" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:4
```

I was wondering what is the right syntax for the server name so I can actually use this kind of URL in my server_name?

Thank you

Comment: The right syntax for [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).  You should be looking at `location` for everything after the hostname.

Comment: can you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to redirect specific URI "http://example.com/directory1/directory2" that who ever visit this uri, will be proxy_pass redirected to internal iis site

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
server_name domain.com;

location /directory1/directory2 {
```